# c++11 thread initialized in constructor to execute method

Tags: multithreading, qt, c++11

I want to render a triangle, whose coordinates are continuously updated (using m_offset) by a separate thread. The thread runs parallel throughout the entire runtime.

My application initializes a QT window with GL widget.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The GL widget (glwidget.cpp) is defined as follows:

```
#include "glwidget.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{

    m_offset = 0.0

    // HERE, I want to start a thread on updateCoordinates().
    // Something like this: (this doesn't work)
    //std::thread mythread (updateCoordinates);   
    // or this (getting segfault)
    //std::thread mythread (&GLWidget::updateCoordinates, this);


}

void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glClearColor(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1);
}
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1,0,0);
        glVertex3f(-0.5+m_offset, -0.5+m_offset, 0);
        glColor3f(0,1,0);
        glVertex3f(0.5+m_offset, -0.5+m_offset, 0);
        glColor3f(0,0,1);
        glVertex3f(0.0+m_offset, 0.5+m_offset, 0);
    glEnd();

}
void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{}


void GLWidget::updateCoordinates()
{

    while(true)
    {
        m_offset += 0.0001;
    }

}
```

Here is the corresponding header:

```
#ifndef GLWIDGET_H
#define GLWIDGET_H

#include <QGLWidget>

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);

    void startSimulation();
    void stopSimulation();
    void updateCoordinates();

private:
    double m_offset;

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // GLWIDGET_H
```

How do I span off a new thread within this class that continuously runs `updateCoordinates()`, while updating the graphics through `paingGL()` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [QThread](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html).

While other options, such as QConcurrent exist, there are those that [question its implementation](https://www.mail-archive.com/development@qt-project.org/msg07794.html).

Create an object derived from QObject, which will be responsible for updating the coordinates. After each update, the object can emit a signal with the coordinates which is then received back on the main thread.

```
class Worker : public QObject 
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Worker();
    ~Worker();

public slots:
    void process();

signals:

    typedef QVector<QPoint> PointList;

    void NewCoordinates(PointList points);

private:
    PointList m_pointList;

private:
};


Worker::Worker() {
    // you could copy data from constructor arguments to internal variables here.
}

// --- DESTRUCTOR ---
Worker::~Worker() {
    // free resources
}


// --- PROCESS ---
// Start processing data.
void Worker::process() {

    // calculate new coordinates...

    emit NewCoordinates(m_pointList);
}
```

Setup and start the thread and worker instance from the main thread..

```
QThread* thread = new QThread;
Worker* worker = new Worker();
worker->moveToThread(thread);

connect(worker, SIGNAL(error(QString)), this, SLOT(errorString(QString)));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(process()));

// tidy up
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

// assuming we're in the MainWindow class, with a NewCoordinates slot function
// collect points - C++ 5 connect syntax
connect(worker, &Worker::NewCoordinates(Worker::PointList), this, &MainWindow::NewCoordinates(Worker::PointList);

// let's go
thread->start();

void MainWindow::NewCoordinates(Worker::PointList pointList)
{
   // handle updated coordinates
}
```

To understand how to really, truly use QThread, there's a great article [here](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QtConcurrent::run` which runs a function in a separate thread.

```
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(this,&GLWidget::updateCoordinates );
```

And in your `updateCoordinates()` function you can emit a signal for example named `repaint` which is connected to `QGLWidget::updateGL` to call `paintGL()` function :

```
void GLWidget::updateCoordinates()
{
    while(true)
    {
        m_offset += 0.0001;
        emit repaint();
    }
}
```

Note that `repaint()` signal should be connected to `updateGL` with connection type of `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`.

There should be also a flag in your while loop which is checked to terminate the while and the thread.

You can check the state of the asynchronous computation represented by the future like:

```
if(future.isRunning())
{
    // It is currently running
}
```

Or wait for it to finish:

```
future1.waitForFinished();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Nejat.
I set everything up as you suggested: 
'connect(this, SIGNAL( repaint() ), this, SLOT( paintGL() ), Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);'
Now paintGL() and updateCoordinates() are alternating in separate threads. That's good. However, strangely, the triangle graphics output does not get updated. I can only see the triangle move, when I resize the window. Do you have an idea why that might be the case?

Comment: @user2926577 You should connect the signal to `QGLWidget::updateGL`. `updateGL` will call `paintGL`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Nejat, that works. The issue I'm having now is that, since the execution of the two threads are alternating (paintGL and updateCoordinates), I only get an overall update rate of 60Hz, which defeats the purpose of using threads. When I remove `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`, I get one paintGL for every 1000 updateCoordinates and an overall update rate of 80kHz (kilo!). However, now I cannot use/click the button in the main window anymore (hourglass cursor). How can I resolve this? - Really appreciate your advice!

Comment: When you remove `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` the connection type becomes `Qt::QueuedConnection` and every emit is inserted in a queue the size of which is increased in time. May be that's because of the much bulk of emitting.